# Validity of style of defining class in namespace

Tags: c++

**Summary:**

Is there any documentation (eg c++ standard) to support the validity of defining a C++ class using the style:

```
namespace N { class X; }
class N::X { ... }
```

**Details:**

We use a couple of styles in some of our company's code to define classes:

```
// n_x.h - style 1
namespace N {
  class X;
}

class N::X {...}
```

and

```
// n_y.h - style 2
namespace N {
  class Y;
}

namespace N {
  class Y { ... };
}
```

The key difference here is between `class N::X` in *style 1* and `namespace N { class Y {...}...`  in *style 2*, ie we wrap class Y in *style 2* in a namespace.

Both styles seem valid to me (we've never had problems compiling them on VS20xx and Clang), but a colleague has questioned whether *style 1* is valid as a tool we are using to analyse our code doesn't properly recognize *class X* to be part of the namespace when using *style 1*.

My hope is that someone can provide me a reference to documentation that shows that *style 1* is a valid way of defining a class in C++.

Comment: I vote for *style* 2, because if there is several classes and structs in namespace it would be (a little bit) easy to change the name of namespace

Comment: Style 1 has advantages. It prevents a level of indentation and catches typos earlier.

Comment: I started using style 1 because of indentation issues (as Simple mentioned) - tools were starting to mess with my identation, or when you have nested namespaces it becomes a bit of a mess. But yes both styles have pros and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this quote from Bjarne Stroustrup's book could serve you.

From chapter 14 of [The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html):

----- (page 392)

> [...]
>
> **14.2.1 Explicit Qualification**
>
> A member can be declared winthin a namespace definition and defined later using the
> namespace-name::member-name notation.
>
> Members of a namespace must be
> introduced using this notation:

```
namespace namespace-name {
   // declarations and definitions
}
```

> For example:

```
namespace Parser {
     double expr(bool); //declaration
     double term(bool);
     double prim(bool);
}

double val = Parser::expr(true); // use

double Parser::expr(bool b) //definition
{
    // ...
}
```

> We cannot declare a new member of a namespace outside a namespace definition using the qualifier syntax (iso.7.3.1.2)....

Comment: I've only got [The C++ Programming Language, Third Edition](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd.html), but there's a similar paragraph in §8.2, pg 167-169 - thanks for that solid source.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, style 1 is valid.

`[namespace.memdef]/2` states:

> Members of a named namespace can also be defined outside that namespace by explicit qualification (3.4.3.2)
>   of the name being defined, provided that the entity being defined was already declared in the namespace
>   and the definition appears after the point of declaration in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s
>   namespace.

Comment: +1 good find... 3.4.2/7 even illustrates how the earlier namespaces might be matched based on `using` statements while latter ones are explicitly listed during a member function definition....

Answer (score 0):

§9 [class]/p11:

> If a *class-head-name* contains a *nested-name-specifier*, the
>   *class-specifier* shall refer to a class that was previously declared directly in the class or namespace to which the
>   *nested-name-specifier* refers, or in an element of the inline namespace set (7.3.1) of that namespace (i.e., not merely inherited or
>   introduced by a *using-declaration*), and the *class-specifier* shall
>   appear in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration. In such
>   cases, the *nested-name-specifier* of the *class-head-name* of the
>   definition shall not begin with a *decltype-specifier*.

*class-head-name* is the term for the thing that names the class being defined. *nested-name-specifier* is the standardese for "everything to the left of `::`, including the `::` itself".

Answer (score 0):

From `A.8 Classes [gram.class]`:

```
...
class-specifier:
    class-head { member-specification_opt }

class-head:
    class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt class-head-name class-virt-specifier_opt
    base-clause_opt class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt base-clause_opt

class-head-name:
    nested-name-specifier_opt class-name

class-virt-specifier:
    final

class-key:
    class
    struct
    union
```

So, an optional `nested-name-specifier`'s allowed between the `class-key` keyword and the `class-name`.  `nested-name-specified`s are documented in `A.4 Expressions [gram.expr]`:

```
nested-name-specifier:
    ::
    type-name ::
    namespace-name ::
    decltype-specifier ::
    nested-name-specifier identifier ::
    nested-name-specifier template_opt simple-template-id ::
```

So `namespace-name`s ***are*** valid in the definition.